# How can I display the UWP control on calendar when we move to previous/next month?

Tags: telerik, uwp

I'm using a [Telerik](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telerik) Calendar control in my view. When we log in, by default it displays the Monthday view with the current date highlighted. Here I want to add the [UWP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Windows_Platform) button control, and it should display when we navigate from the current month to the previous/next month.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [navigation methods for the RadCalendar](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radcalendar/navigation-support/programaticnavigation) in the Button's click event handler.

For future reference, you can find a list of the [RadCalendar's Properties and configurations here](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/universal-windows-platform/controls/radcalendar/propertiesandconfiguration).